# How do you turn off compression on a specific page?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, compression

When compression is turned on globally for the root website, is there a way to turn compression off for a specific page? (ex. download.aspx)  I would like to turn it off on a few select pages where we are streaming files to the client. I'm using IIS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.  You can do it using adsutil.vbs.  The syntax will be something like this:

```
cscript C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/{siteID}/Root/{subfolder}{page.asp}/DoDynamicCompression False
```

Comment: great, thanks Scott. (Sorry, I don't have enough rep on serverfault to give vote you up.)

Comment: Great, glad that worked for you!